# String format in java?

Tags: java, string-formatting

Input String: 115.0000

Output String should be like: 115.00

i used this code:

```
String.format("%.2f","115.0000");
```

i got `IllegalArgumentException`. What can i do now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're submitting a string, but telling it to expect a floating point value.  Remove the quotes around the number (second parameter).

Answer (score 4):

```
String.format("%.2f", Double.parseDouble("115.0000"));
```